# Orchard 1.7 publish error: The "MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks.XmlDelete" task could not be loaded from the assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, publish, orchardcms-1.7

I have a local Orchard 1.7 cms site, which i have customized and so forth. My task is now to publish my site to my host(arvixe.com) through Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 - via the publish option. But the publish fails and i get this error:

```
Error   1   The "MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks.XmlDelete" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\WilliamHolm\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\whj\src\Orchard.Web\..\Tools\MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks\bin\Release\MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks.dll. Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\WilliamHolm\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\whj\src\Tools\MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks\bin\Release\MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.   C:\Users\WilliamHolm\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\whj\src\Orchard.Web\Orchard.Web.csproj   247 5   Orchard.Web
```

by looking at the source where the error is located around line 247, in the Orchard.Web.csproj, it looks like this:

```
</Target>
  <Import Project="$(ProjectDir)..\..\lib\msbuild\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
  <UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(ProjectDir)..\Tools\MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks\bin\Release\MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks.dll" TaskName="MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks.XmlDelete" />
  <Target Name="ProcessConfigurationFiles" AfterTargets="CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMsdeploy">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <PackageTmp>$(ProjectDir)obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp</PackageTmp>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <!-- extra processing of the staged config files -->
    <XmlUpdate XmlFileName="$(PackageTmp)\web.config" XPath="/configuration/system.web/compilation/@debug" Value="false" />
    <XmlDelete XmlFileName="$(PackageTmp)\web.config" XPath="/configuration/system.web/trust" />
    <XmlUpdate XmlFileName="$(PackageTmp)\web.config" XPath="/configuration/system.web/machineKey/@validationKey" Value="AutoGenerate" />
    <XmlUpdate XmlFileName="$(PackageTmp)\web.config" XPath="/configuration/system.web/machineKey/@decryptionKey" Value="AutoGenerate" />
    <XmlUpdate XmlFileName="$(PackageTmp)\Config\log4net.config" XPath="/log4net/appender/immediateFlush/@value" Value="false" />
    <XmlUpdate XmlFileName="$(PackageTmp)\Config\log4net.config" XPath="/log4net/logger/priority/@value" Value="ERROR" />
    <XmlUpdate XmlFileName="$(PackageTmp)\Config\log4net.config" XPath="/log4net/root/priority/@value" Value="ERROR" />
    <XmlDelete XmlFileName="$(PackageTmp)\Config\log4net.config" XPath="/log4net/appender[@name='debug-file']" />
    <XmlDelete XmlFileName="$(PackageTmp)\Config\log4net.config" XPath="/log4net/appender[@name='debugger']" />
    <XmlDelete XmlFileName="$(PackageTmp)\Config\log4net.config" XPath="/log4net/appender[@name='error-file']/filter" />
    <XmlDelete XmlFileName="$(PackageTmp)\Config\log4net.config" XPath="/log4net/logger[@name='Orchard.Localization']" />
    <XmlDelete XmlFileName="$(PackageTmp)\Config\log4net.config" XPath="/log4net/logger[@name='Orchard']" />
    <XmlDelete XmlFileName="$(PackageTmp)\Config\log4net.config" XPath="/log4net/root/appender-ref[@ref='debug-file']" />
    <!-- disable all file monitoring but ExtensionMonitoringCorrdinator to detect new modules/themes -->
    <XmlUpdate XmlFileName="$(PackageTmp)\Config\HostComponents.config" XPath="/HostComponents/Components/Component/Properties/Property[@Name='DisableMonitoring']/@Value" Value="true" />
  </Target>
```

The closest ting i can find on this, is this thread:

http://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/19688

and i have tried those advices, but it keeps failing.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

THX in advance.

/Will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was that i had only built the project in "Debug" configuration, while my publishing option was looking for "Release". So I only changed it to "Release" in the Solutions Configurations and pressed --> Build/Build Solution. That worked!

/Will.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Please change following path to =>

```
<UsingTask AssemblyFile="C:\Users\Shaun\Documents\@GitHub\CertifiedOverheadCrane\orchard1x\src\Tools\MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks\bin\Release\MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks.dll"
           TaskName="MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks.XmlDelete" />
```

Original:

```
<!--<UsingTask AssemblyFile="$(ProjectDir)\..\Tools\MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks\bin\Release\MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks.dll" 
         TaskName="MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks.XmlDelete" />-->
```

Don't forget to restart VS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, have tested it out, but still have the same error. But when i look into the folder ..Tools\MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks\bin\Release\ the folder is empty, so no wonder it can not find it. So is your Release folder also empty? or am i missing something?

Comment: Never mind the previous comment, i had not set the build configuration to "Release", so now i have files in the .Tools\MSBuild.Orchard.Tasks\bin\Release\